# How do you stop all running threads in Python when one fails?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, scapy, arp

I am currently working on a Python 3 script that is designed to stress test an ARP service. Currently, I am creating up to 255 "worker" threads and then having them send up to 2^15 packets to stress test the server. This is the main test script that I run:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(0, 8):
        for j in range(0, 15):
            print("Multithreading test with", 2**i, "workers and ", 2**j,
                  "packets:")
            sleep(3)
            try:
                arp_load_test.__main__(2**i)
            except:
                print("Multithreading test failed at", 2**i, "workers and ",
                      2**j, "packets:")
                break

    print("Moving on to the multiprocessing test.")
    sleep(10)

    for i in range(0, 15):
        print("Multiprocessing test with", 2**i, "workers:")
        sleep(3)
        try:
            arp_load_test2.__main__(2**i)
        except:
            print("Multiprocessing test failed at", 2**i, "workers.")
            print("\n\n\t\t\t\tDONE!")
            break
```

The first code block tests the multithreading and the second does the same thing except with multiprocessing. `arp_load_test.py` is a multithreading version of `arp_load_test2.py`'s multiprocessing. In the `except` part of each of the `for` loops I want to end the loop as soon as one of the threads fails. How do I do that? Here's the code for `arp_load_test.py`, and `arp_load_test2.py` is almost the exact same thing:

```
def __main__(threaders = 10, items = 10):
    print("\tStarting threading main method\n")
    sleep(1)
    a = datetime.datetime.now()
    # create a logger object
    logging.basicConfig(filename = "arp_multithreading_log.txt",
                        format = "%(asctime)s %(message)s",
                        level = logging.INFO)

    # default values
    interface = "enp0s8"
    workers = threaders
    packets = items
    dstip = "192.168.30.1"
    # parse the command line
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "i:w:n:d:", ["interface=",
                                                              "workers=",
                                                              "packets=",
                                                              "dstip="])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print("Error: ", str(err), file = sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(-1)
    # override defaults with the options passed in on the command line
    for o, a in opts:
        if o in ("-i", "--interface"):
            interface = a
        elif o in ("-w", "--workers"):
            w = int(a)
            if w > 254:
                workers = 254
                print("Max worker threads is 254. Using 254 workers",
                      file = sys.stderr)
            elif w < 1:
                workers = 1
                print("Min worker threads is 1. Using 1 worker",
                      file = sys.stderr)
            else:
                workers = w
        elif o in ("-n", "--packets"):
            packets = int(a)
        elif o in ("-d", "--dstip"):
            dstip = a
        else:
            assert False, "unhandled option"
    # create an empty list as a thread pool
    office = []
    # give all the workers jobs in the office
    for i in range(workers):
        office.append(ArpTestThread(i, "ARP-" + str(i), i, interface, packets,
                                    dstip))

    # do all the work
    logging.info("BEGIN ARP FLOOD TEST")
    for worker in office:
        worker.daemon = True
        worker.start()
    for worker in office:
        worker.join()

    b = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("\tSent", len(office) * packets, "packets!\n")
    print("It took", a - b, "seconds!")
    logging.info("END ARP FLOOD TEST\n")
    sleep(5)
    ##### end __main__
```

`ArpTestThread` is an child object of `threading.Thread` (or `Process`) that is set up to send the packets to the ARP service. Also, I'm running the test script from inside of a VM via Terminal, but I am not using any of the command line options the program is set up to use, I just added parameters instead b/c lazy.

---

Do I need to place a `try block` inside of the class file instead of the test script? I was given 90% of the class file code already complete, and am updating it and trying to collect data on what it does, along with optimizing it to properly stress the ARP service. I want the `for` loops in the test script (the very first portion of code in this post) to break, stop all currently running threads, and print out at what point the program failed as soon as one of the threads/processes crashes. Is that possible?

---

EDIT:
The suggested duplicate question does not solve my problem. I am trying to send packets, and it does not raise an exception until the program essentially runs out of memory to continue sending packets to the ARP service. I don’t get an exception until the program itself breaks, so the possible solution that suggested using a simple signal does not work.

The program can finish successfully. Threads/processes can (and should) get started, send a packet, and then close up. If something happens in any singular thread/process, I want everything currently running to stop and then essentially print out an error message to the console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use Events, Semaphores, Locks, Conditions, or a combination thereof to manage safely exiting my multithreaded Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731203/should-i-use-events-semaphores-locks-conditions-or-a-combination-thereof-to)

Comment: See my edit, that question is related but not the same, and deals with a different problem. Thank you though

Comment: The duplicate question gives answer to  *"How do you stop all running threads in Python when one fails?"* This question contains a lot of text and a lot of code, much of it not needed, but in the end it asks just that.

Comment: You also wrote *"I want to end the loop as soon as one of the threads fails"*. But you never say what it means that a thread *fails*. In my answer in the duplicate, the thread sets a flag when it *fails*. The same should probably be done here as well.

Comment: A thread failing means that it encountered some sort of Exception of some sort, either because the program crashed, the ARP service crashed, or some other Error was found

Comment: The page you linked @zvone only shows how to set it up if you want it to run until there's an error. I want to possibly have a completely fine run. The threads are started, send a packet, and close. If that happens without error then the program should finish up.