# What is the proper way to terminate multi-threading code when one thread fails?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
def getdata3(self, page, data, apifolder, additional):
    tries = 10
    for n in range(tries):
        try:
        except (ChunkedEncodingError, requests.exceptions.HTTPError) as e:
            ...

            if n == tries - 1:
                raise e            # If arrived here - Terminate !
    print ("{2} page {0} finished. Length is {1}".format(page,len(datarALL),str(datetime.now())))
    return job
```

Main code:

```
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_of_workers) as executor:
        futh = [(executor.submit(self.getdata3, page, data, apifolder,additional)) for page in pages]
        for data in as_completed(futh):
            datarALL.extend(data.result())
    print ("Finished generateing data.")
    return datarALL
```

This code create threads for workers. When all work is done it returns the `datarALL` .

**My problem:**

What I want is that if one of the threads arrives here:

```
if n == tries - 1:
    raise e            # If arrived here - Terminate !
```

All existed threads will be terminated. No future threads will be created (terminate the `for page in pages` loop) and the entire program will be terminated.

I read a few articles about the issue. I also read this [Should I use Events, Semaphores, Locks, Conditions, or a combination thereof to manage safely exiting my multithreaded Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731203/should-i-use-events-semaphores-locks-conditions-or-a-combination-thereof-to)  but the offered solutions are very complex and seem to add a lot code which I doubt I need.

I tried to do:

```
if n == tries - 1:
    exit(1)
```

But when I check `htop` this doesn't shut down the entire process and threads.. I have some left over that are staying there as zombies.

**My Question:**
Is there a simple, clean solution to terminate the program with error notice?

Comment: Are you using threading or multiprocesses? Threads can be marked as "daemon threads". As such they will automatically be terminated if the main thread terminates. However, this may not be a good approach, since in that case they will not have a chance to terminate gracefully (and do clean-up et c.).

Comment: @JohanL threading.. notice the `ThreadPoolExecutor` in my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.exit()` can stay stuck sometimes because it tries to exit gracefully.

Some quick & dirty solution implies the use of `os._exit(1)` (1 is a possible return code indicating an error, 0 means success, you don't want to use that here. Stay in 0-255 range to avoid portability problems)

On modern systems, resource tracking happens and the program quits, killing all attached resources (file handles, threads, memory...), so it is an acceptable solution.

The downside is that it bypasses python exit/cleanup procedures, just like when you kill the python process using `kill`. On OSes lacking resource tracking management (we're talking ancient history), this would result in global memory leak/file descriptors.

In your case, it doesn't matter because without this you cannot quit your application. But don't generalize it, reserve that for emergency exit procedures.

Comment: why does it work with os._exit(1) but not with os._exit("msg") ?

Comment: you cannot return a string as an exit code. OSes return with exit _codes_ not strings (yes, this is less friendly than python, if you need to, you can write the actual error message in a file)

Comment: ok. I don't actualy care about the returned value... It just prints it to the log and the task is being retry. why did you say this is a dirty solution? what is the downside? I'm using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: the downside is that it bypasses python exit procedures, just like when you kill the python process using `kill`. In your case, it doesn't matter because the alternative is: you cannot quit